# Spring Security : Could access to current user principle when using UserDetailesService

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I have a AuthenticationProvider with type userDetailsService  as follow:

```
public class CustomUDS implements UserDetailsService {

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String clientId) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
          ClientDetails client=clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientId);
          String password=client.getClientSecret();
          boolean enabled=true;
          boolean accountNonExpired=true;
          boolean credentialsNonExpired=true;
          boolean accountNonLocked=true;
          List<GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
          GrantedAuthority roleClient=new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_CLIENT");
          authorities.add(roleClient);
          return new User(clientId,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        }
}
```

when user is logged and I use follow statement to fetch user's username, it returns string value of User class:

```
Object object = SpringSecurityContext.getcontext().getAuthentication.getPrinciple();
```

object value will be string

> "org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@db343434: Username
>   ...."

and I could not convert return object to User or UserDetails.

now, how can I access to user's username?

Comment: Principle? I think you mean Principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So try this to get username:

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
String name = userDetails.getUsername();
```

Comment: what ?? I need user's username in several point of my web application during run time !

Comment: I say that, I could not convert string to UserDetails object, It will return type cast exception.

Comment: @M2E67 Why do you think that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` returns a String? Did you try the above code?